# binary file data interpretation in perl

Tags: perl, binary

I have a problem in interpreting the bytes from binary file in perl.

Snippet of the code :

```
open IMG_FH, $IMAGE_FILE or die $!;
binmode IMG_FH;

sysread(IMG_FH, $Var_Options, 2);

if ($Var_Options == 0)
{
    print "Received 0\n";
}
elsif ($Var_Options == 28)
{
    print "Received 0\n";
}
else
{
    print "Error\n";
}
```

Even though I am sure that the word kept at the start of the binary file is : "001c" (Hexadecimal), I am ending up printing "Error";

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tools if you're analyzing binary data.

Instead of doing a simple numeric equality test, you need to study [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html), [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html), and the [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html).

One very helpful tool is to use [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) or the core library [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html).

I would rewrite your script to the following to inspect the first two bytes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'test-all-the-things.jpg';

open my $fh, '<:raw', $file;

sysread $fh, my $data, 2;

use Data::Dump;
dd $data;
```

Outputs:

```
"\xFF\xD8"
```

This module adapts the output when one tries to analyze more than just 2 bytes:

```
sysread $fh, my $data, 20;

use Data::Dump;
dd $data;
```

Outputs:

```
pack("H*","ffd8ffe000104a46494600010101006000600000")
```